# Accessing a config.properties file in another class

Tags: java, properties

I have a list of environment specific properties in a config.properties file which is in a resources folder. I then have a seperate Class called GetDatabase.java which I want to grab values from the config file. File structure is below.

```
├───main
│   ├───java
│   └───resources
│
└───test
    ├───java
    │   ├───Database
    │          GetDatabase.java
    │
    └───Resources
        │
        ├───resources
               config.properties
```

My config file entries look like this:

```
dev1URL=https://mos-dev.1.com
dev2URL=https://mos-dev.2.com
dev3URL=https://mos-dev.3.com
```

In my GetDatabase class I have written some code using the getProperty method to call the property file but it's returning as null. Am I missing something here?

Below is the GetDatabase class:

```
package Database;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class GetDatabase {

{
    final ClassLoader loader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    try {
        try (InputStream config = loader.getResourceAsStream("config.properties")) {
            properties.load(config);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public ResultSet runQuery(String strQuery) throws SQLException {

        String driver = properties.getProperty("dev1URL");
        System.out.println("db driver string is here " + driver);
```

Comment: You don't load the config.properties...

Comment: Also returning a ResultSet is 99.99% bad design

Comment: @Lino Thanks. May need to look into this then. But it seems to work for now so I'll have to revisit this another day. That's another topic though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load the properties in an *instance initializer block*:

```
public class GetDatabase {
    private final Properties properties = new Properties();
    {
        final ClassLoader loader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        try(InputStream config = loader.getResourceAsStream("config.properties")){
            properties.load(config);
        } catch(IOException e){
            throw new IOError(e);
        }
    }

    // The rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Should it be InputStream rather than Inputstream?

Comment: @Matt yes exaclty wrote that from my mobile :)

Comment: I have had to slightly change the suggested code. But it now fails at the row with properties.load(config); I will update the original code with what the GetDatabase class looks like now

Comment: @Matt no need for two times writing a try-catch, I've updated my answer on how to do it. Also, can you please tell, *what* is not working?

Comment: Cheers. I updated the code. I get an error for java.lang.NullPointerException: inStream parameter is null and it seems to fail at the row with properties.load(config);

Comment: @Matt do you have another folder in the `Resources` folder? If yes, then try `"resources/config.properties"` as a path

Comment: Bingo! I just moved the config file directly into the Resources folder rather than the sub folder and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help with this, really appreciate it as I was completely stuck.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried for classpath file like:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class App {

  public static void main( String[] args ){

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;

        try {

            String filename = "config.properties";
            input = App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
            if(input==null){
                    System.out.println("Sorry, unable to find " + filename);
                return;
            }

            //load a properties file from class path, inside static method
            prop.load(input);

                //get the property value and print it out
                System.out.println(prop.getProperty("database"));
                System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbuser"));
                System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbpassword"));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            if(input!=null){
                try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

source: [java-properties-file-examples](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/)

Comment: I was wondering if I was going about this too simplistically. Do I need to create another class to read the config file and call this class from my GetDatabase then?

Comment: I think you can simply load the config.properties in your GetDatabase class.